# android studio Native C++ template project [CXX1405] error when building with cmake using CMakeLists.txt: C++ build system [configure] failed

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, compiler-errors, building

I have an error message when I try build grandle Native C++ template project on android studio, I've not modified anything in the files, it's just a simple template project.

Console log:

```
> Task :prepareKotlinBuildScriptModel UP-TO-DATE
[CXX1405] error when building with cmake using C:\Users\both\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\src\main\cpp\CMakeLists.txt: C++ build system [configure] failed while executing:
    @echo off
    "C:\\Users\\both\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\cmake\\3.18.1\\bin\\cmake.exe" ^
      "-HC:\\Users\\both\\AndroidStudioProjects\\MyApplication\\app\\src\\main\\cpp" ^
      "-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Android" ^
      "-DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=ON" ^
      "-DCMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION=29" ^
      "-DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-29" ^
      "-DANDROID_ABI=x86" ^
      "-DCMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI=x86" ^
      "-DANDROID_NDK=C:\\Users\\both\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\23.1.7779620" ^
      "-DCMAKE_ANDROID_NDK=C:\\Users\\both\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\23.1.7779620" ^
      "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\\Users\\both\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\23.1.7779620\\build\\cmake\\android.toolchain.cmake" ^
      "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:\\Users\\both\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\cmake\\3.18.1\\bin\\ninja.exe" ^
      "-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\both\\AndroidStudioProjects\\MyApplication\\app\\build\\intermediates\\cxx\\Debug\\6n168485\\obj\\x86" ^
      "-DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\both\\AndroidStudioProjects\\MyApplication\\app\\build\\intermediates\\cxx\\Debug\\6n168485\\obj\\x86" ^
      "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug" ^
      "-BC:\\Users\\both\\AndroidStudioProjects\\MyApplication\\app\\.cxx\\Debug\\6n168485\\x86" ^
      -GNinja
  from C:\Users\both\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1m 7s
```